# Skip over all lines in a data file before and including a regular string in a loop in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have an instrument that produces data files which contain a large amount of header information. I want to read many files in at a time and `rbind` them together. To read these in successfully I have been using the following loop and skip to deal with the header information:

```
df <- c()
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.cnv", recursive=TRUE)) {
u <-read.table(x, skip=100)
      df <- rbind(df, u)
}
```

Here is an example of what the datafile with 5 lines to skip looks like:

```
# Header information
# Header information
# Header information
# Header information
# Header information
*END*
      0.571    26.6331     8.2733    103.145     0.0842  -0.000049  0.000e+00
      0.576    26.6316     8.2756    103.171     0.3601  -0.000049  0.000e+00
      0.574    26.6322     8.2744    103.157     0.3613  -0.000046  0.000e+00
```

The issue is that the number of lines to skip is dynamic and I would like to come up with a generalized solution. Fortunately, every file ends with this:

```
*END*
```

So my question is, how can I read in a file with the above that skips over all lines before and includes the `*END*` line? This likely would take place before `rbind`-ing them together.

Comment: which file format do you have? .csv .xls or something else?

Comment: So reading the files in and deleting the header afterwards is not an option?

Comment: The filetype is .cnv which is an ASCII text based file. Basically can consider it a .txt file. Reading in and deleting I don't think is an option and I am actually using a loop to read in many files then `rbind` those together. Left my example simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the input line by line using

```
all_content = readLines("input.txt")
>all_content
[1] "# Header information"                                                         
[2] "# Header information"                                                         
[3] "# Header information"                                                         
[4] "# Header information"                                                         
[5] "# Header information"                                                         
[6] "*END*"                                                                        
[7] "      0.571    26.6331     8.2733    103.145     0.0842  -0.000049  0.000e+00"
[8] "      0.576    26.6316     8.2756    103.171     0.3601  -0.000049  0.000e+00"
[9] "      0.574    26.6322     8.2744    103.157     0.3613  -0.000046  0.000e+00"
```

And remove the lines till you hit *END* using `grep` as follow

```
skip = all_content[-c(1:grep("*END*",all_content))]
```

Now read using the normal `read.table` function as follow

```
input <- read.table(textConnection(skip))
> input
     V1      V2     V3      V4     V5       V6 V7
1 0.571 26.6331 8.2733 103.145 0.0842 -4.9e-05  0
2 0.576 26.6316 8.2756 103.171 0.3601 -4.9e-05  0
3 0.574 26.6322 8.2744 103.157 0.3613 -4.6e-05  0
```

You get the desired result.

**UPDATE**

In your loop just use

```
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.cnv", recursive=TRUE)) {
   all_content <- readLines(x)
   skip = all_content[-c(1:grep("*END*",all_content))]
   input <- read.table(textConnection(skip))
   df <- rbind(df, input)
}
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified my example. I am using a loop and have made some edits to my question above for clarity. Any ideas how to adapt this to what I've described above?

Comment: For some reason, on some files, the result of `grep("*END*",all_content)` yields two numbers `2` and then lines with the `*END*` on it. I got around it for now by doing this `max(grep("*END*",all_content))`. However, does this make any sense to you? There is only one instance of `*END*` in every file. Just seems odd.

Comment: Can you please reproduce the case for one of those files. It's hard to guess what is happening and what's going wrong just by looking at your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `skip` option in `data.table::fread()`

```
library(data.table)
dT = fread("# Header information
  # Header information
  # Header information
  # Header information
  # Header information
  *END*
    0.571    26.6331     8.2733    103.145     0.0842  -0.000049  0.000e+00
  0.576    26.6316     8.2756    103.171     0.3601  -0.000049  0.000e+00
  0.574    26.6322     8.2744    103.157     0.3613  -0.000046  0.000e+00", 
  skip ="*END*")
```