# skip rows until certain 'value' is found - bulk CSV upload, inconsistent pattern of row numbers

Tags: r, csv, stringr, read.table, readr

I am trying to bulk load and merge two dozen CSV files in R. I am adding a column to my data frame to identify each file by its file name in a column called 'file_name'.

Each file has a number of rows on top that are superfluous. Originally I thought it was a consistent pattern of 16 rows. I leveraged the 'skiprow' command within the read_csv function to address that issue.

However, after closer inspection I discovered that the pattern of 16 rows is inconsistent from file to file. The only consistent pattern I found was that all the 'good data' in each file comes right after a line that says "Attendee Details"

I am trying to figure out a way to skip all the rows before and including the row containing the text "Attendee Details".

Here is my code so far:

```
list_of_files <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')

df <- list_of_files %>%
  setNames(nm = .) %>% 
  map_df(~read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(), col_names = FALSE), .id = "file_name")
```

**Here is what my data looks like:**
[image: What my data looks like]

**Here is what I am hoping to load for each file while also skipping over that header row:**
[image]

I already tried to redesign/configure the code snippets I found in this thread - unfortunately I hit errors and am a bit stuck on where to go from here.

[Skip over all lines in a data file before and including a regular string in a loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289483/skip-over-all-lines-in-a-data-file-before-and-including-a-regular-string-in-a-lo)

```
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.csv", recursive=TRUE)) {
   all_content <- readLines(x)
   skip = all_content[-c(1:grep("Attendee Details",all_content))]
   input <- read.table(textConnection(skip))
   df <- rbind(df, input)
}

Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 1 did not have 13 elements
```

Any pointers? Also, I know it is preferred to post a reproducible example here - I couldn't quite figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Ok please provide a dput for one or two dfs please it can be based on this photo

Answer (score 0):

1) As a pointer:

- did you initialize `df`, as in the example? (cbind expects same number of columns, which you apparently do not have here)
- are there files without data after the header string? (you might want to exclude those before performing `cbind`, so maybe read them into a list first)
- do the files have varying number of columns after the header string? (same idea as before, either exclude those or use `fill = TRUE`)

Here is one possible solution with `data.table`, that also illustrates a reproducible example (but may not consider specifics of you files, obviously):

```r
library(data.table)

makeHeader <- function(x){
    fn <- paste0("myfile_", sprintf("%02d", x), ".csv")
    cat("Attendee report\n", file=fn, append = FALSE)
    cat("Report Generated,01/01/2020\n", file=fn, append = TRUE)
    cat("Topic,topic ", x, "\n", file=fn, append = TRUE)
    cat("Attendee Details\n", file=fn, append = TRUE)
}

# generate files:
set.seed(1)
bigdt <- data.table(col1 = sample(1:12, 1.2e4, replace = TRUE),
                    col2 = sample(LETTERS[1:26], 1.2e4, replace = TRUE),
                    col3 = sample(20:50, 1.2e4, replace = TRUE))
biglist <- split(bigdt, ceiling(seq_len(dim(bigdt)[1])/1e3))
rm(bigdt)
invisible(lapply(seq_along(biglist), makeHeader))
invisible(lapply(seq_along(biglist), 
    function(x) fwrite(biglist[[x]], 
        file=paste0("myfile_", sprintf("%02d", x), ".csv"), append=TRUE, col.names = TRUE)))

# read files and combine; add column for file name
files <- list.files(pattern="myfile_.*.csv")
DT <- lapply(files, function(x) fread(x, skip="Attendee Details", sep=","))
names(DT) <- files
rbindlist(DT, idcol = "file", fill=TRUE)
#>                 file col1 col2 col3
#>     1: myfile_01.csv    9    N   48
#>     2: myfile_01.csv    4    V   33
#>     3: myfile_01.csv    7    X   22
#>     4: myfile_01.csv    1    W   49
#>     5: myfile_01.csv    2    X   34
#>    ---                             
#> 11996: myfile_12.csv   10    S   29
#> 11997: myfile_12.csv    5    T   25
#> 11998: myfile_12.csv    8    B   34
#> 11999: myfile_12.csv   11    P   43
#> 12000: myfile_12.csv    1    O   37
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Appreciate your feedback here...I did initialize df as shown in the example, but no luck. As far as column numbers, I have spot checked a handful of them and all appear to have 10 columns. That said, it is possible that they differ. Is there a quick way to analyze how many columns each of my files has without merging/loading them all? Setting fill=true did not work as expected. I also tried to run your code, but it wound up creating a number of strange columns of data...understandably I didn't give you my data, so likely the culprit. Are you able to tell me more about the function you wrote?

Comment: If you ran `DT <- lapply(files, function(x) fread(x, skip="Attendee Details", sep=","))`, then `DT` should be a list of `data.tables`. `lapply(DT, ncol)` would give you the number of columns of each file. Just typing `DT` would give you an idea of the columns that were created in each file, and what went wrong. You have to adjust the `files` line to only include the files you are interested in.